# Question related to electric force between two lines of charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, integration

[image]

Not sure how to go about integrating the equation for this example. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you include the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, every infinitesimal charge element of the first rod will exert a force in every infinitesimal charge element of the rod. This can be resolved by finding the force exerted by the rod on a single point charge (of the second rod) and them integrating that expression again over the length of the second rod.

Firstly, use the standard method to find the electric force between a point charge, $q$, and one of the metal rods seperated by a distance, say, $S$. **(Note that $S$ would be a constant in this case.)**

One you have found the expression for the force between  the rod and a point charge $q$, you basically just have to sum of all such forces exerted by the rod on every infinitesimal charge element of the second rod. Just replace $q$ with $dq$, $F$ (in the expression you just found) with $dF$ and vary $S$ over the entire length of the second rod. **(Now $S$ will be the variable to be integrated.)**

You will arrive at an expression involving the natural log. The limit as $l$ approaches 0 can be taken using L’Hôpital’s rule and you should arrive at the force between 2 point charges separated by a distance $d$.

Comment: I suggest to edit in your Profile your user name with lower case letters like 'OverWootch'. With capital letters it's like to cry loudly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take an elemental length d$l$ on any of the rods. Now find the charge that resides on this elemental length. Now find the force on this elemental charge. Now proceed as usual.